# Saving values in data frame from nested loops in R

Tags: r

Folks, I'm probably making a mountain out of a molehill, but I'm stuck with something on R. Here is what I want to do: Solve a linear programming problem for multiple weights on x1 and x2, using a loop. The loop and the function work just fine, but I am unable to store the data in a vector and that's frustrating. Note: **I am a beginner/novice in R**

```
library(lpSolve)
# Set up problem to maximize
# a1*x1 + a2*x2  
# subject to
# x1 + x2 <= 500
# 8x1 - 9x2 = 0


#Creating the constraint matrix
f.con <- matrix (c(1, 1, 8, -9), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)

#Creating the vector for operators
f.dir <- c("<=", "=")

#Creating the Right hand side of the constraints in the above problem. 
f.rhs <- c(500, 0)
#
# Now run the program
#

#Create vector to store maximized objective values
ans <- vector('numeric')


#Create loop sequences for a1 and a2
a1 <- seq(0.1,1,0.1)
a2 <- seq(0.1,1,0.1)

#Run for lop with lp function
for(i in a1){
  for(j in a2){
      if(i+j)==1{
      ans[i] <- lp("max", c(i,j), f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$objval
    }  
  }
}
```

Nothing gets stored in ans, it should be a vector of length 10. **What am I doing wrong? :(**

Comment: end it like at the last curly brace "} -> my_vec"

Comment: @ElioDiaz, have you been able to get it to return vectors like that? Last I checked, the best you can hope for is the return value from the last statement (which is most certainly not everything).

Comment: `ans <- lapply(seq(0.1,1,0.1), function(i) lp("max", c(i,1-i), f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$objval)` might work.

Comment: @r2evans it worked. Perfect! But since I am unfamiliar with the apply family of functions, can you point out what's wrong with my code as well! There has to be a way using nested loops.

Comment: If you run through the code, you'll see that on the first call to `lp()`, you are trying to assing it to `ans[0.1]`, which is meaningless. You might have been able to do `for (ind in seq_along(i)) ans[ind] <- lp("max", c(i[ind], 1-i[ind]), ...)$objval)` as well. In R, though, I suggest you should learn to think about things in *vectorizing* mechanisms (often using one of the `apply` functions), where its efficiency really shines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things with your code:

- as @MillionC pointed out, your conditional is syntactically wrong, it should have more enclosing parens as in `if ((i+j)==1) {...`
- the first time `lp(...)` is called, it is being assigned to `ans[0.1]`, which is nonsensical, you probably need to iterate over the *indices* of `a1` (and optionally `a2`)
- your pre-allocation of `ans` is not necessarily *wrong*, but pre-allocating does very little unless you tell it its size; I suggest `ans <- vector('numeric', length(a1))` or just `ans <- numeric(length(a1))`
- perhaps you trivialized the example for the question, but just in case ... you do not need two loops, when your conditional allows you to know ahead of time which combinations of `i` and `j` are relevant; in this case, you only need `j` when it is perfectly `1-i`, so you can remove a loop entirely.

You could use:

```
ans <- vector('numeric', length(a1))
for (indi in seq_along(a1)) {
  for (indj in seq_along(a2)) {
    if ((a1[indi]+a2[indj]) == 1) {
      ans[indi] <- 99 + a1[indi]
    }  
  }
}
ans
#  [1] 99.1 99.2 99.3 99.4 99.5 99.6 99.7 99.8 99.9  0.0
```

or slightly better:

```
ans <- vector('numeric', length(a1))
for (indi in seq_along(a1)) {
  ans[indi] <- 99 + a1[indi]
}
ans
#  [1]  99.1  99.2  99.3  99.4  99.5  99.6  99.7  99.8  99.9 100.0
```

(I don't have `lpSolve`, so I'm masquerading with "99".) The big difference here is the value of the last call: in your double-loop, there is never a value in `a2` that when added to the `a1` value of 1 equals 1. However, the second run does not check for that, so ... it does something. (Only you know which method is correct.)

Nested loops are not necessarily wrong, but in general I suggest you think about how to vectorize something. Instead of looping over things in ways you'd expect to in C or Java (and sometimes Python), think about doing things to a vector all at once. Sometimes this is as simple as replacing

```
vec <- 1:10
for (ind in seq_along(vec)) vec[ind] <- vec^2
```

to

```
vec <- 1:10
vec <- vec^2
```

as long as the function supports a vector as an input. When it is not supported or is not as simple as thing, then `sapply` and `lapply` are sort of like a `for` loop but capturing each return value, so you can do something like

```
ans <- sapply(seq_along(a1), function(indi) 99 + a1[indi])
ans
#  [1]  99.1  99.2  99.3  99.4  99.5  99.6  99.7  99.8  99.9 100.0
```

Care must be taken to not go too literally with this. For instance, converting your conditioned double-lool, we would get:

```
ans <- sapply(seq_along(a1), function(indi) {
  sapply(seq_along(a2), function(indj) {
    if ((a1[indi]+a2[indj]) == 1) {
      99 + a1[indi]
    } else {
      # something here?
    }
  })
})
ans
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 99.9 NULL 
#  [2,] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 99.8 NULL NULL 
#  [3,] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 99.7 NULL NULL NULL 
#  [4,] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 99.6 NULL NULL NULL NULL 
#  [5,] NULL NULL NULL NULL 99.5 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
#  [6,] NULL NULL NULL 99.4 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
#  [7,] NULL NULL 99.3 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
#  [8,] NULL 99.2 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
#  [9,] 99.1 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
# [10,] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

... which is likely not correct for you. It is not hard to correct for this, but in general you probably want to run the loop only where needed, not 10x the runs.

In another extreme solution, you know the values of `a2` that are relevant for each in `a1`, then consider pre-allocating them and using a cousin of `sapply`:

```
myfunc <- function(i, j) lp("max", c(i,j), f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$objval
ans <- mapply(myfunc, a1, a2)
```

(I pre-defined `myfunc` for demonstration purposes; it's legit and common to put the `function(i,j)...` directly as the first argument to `mapply`, as I did for the second argument to `sapply` above.)

This is a "zipper" like function, where the calls are effectively

```
myfunc(i[1], j[1])
myfunc(i[2], j[2])
myfunc(i[3], j[3])
...
myfunc(i[10], j[10])
```

captured into a vector. This method might be more appropriate for you, where you know the pairs of arguments that need to be given as a vector to the second argument in `lp(..., c(i,j), ...)`.

(Note: `mapply` can take an arbitrary number of arguments, so it could also do

```
mapply(function(w,x,y,z) { ... },
       list(...), list(...), list(...), list(...))
```

The only requirement is that each list is either the same length or length 1.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ending parentheses of your if statement should be around the "1" and not the "j". Like:

```
if(i+j==1){
```

Comment: That is certainly a problem, good find, but it does not address intended question. Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: This was just a typo on the code I wrote here. Sorry about that.